# explicit relation between interior derivative and alternation operation

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a vector field, $L_X$ the Lie derivative, $i_X$ the interior derivative, $A$  the alternation operation (that assign for each covariant tensor field $K$, a differential form $AK$).

The definitions I am following are:

$$(AK)(X_1,\cdots, X_r)=
 \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_r}{\rm sgn}(\sigma)K(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(r)}) $$
$$L_X(\omega)(X_1,\cdots,X_k)=X(\omega(X_1,\cdots,X_k))
-\sum_{i=1}^k \omega(X_1,\cdots, [X,X_i],\cdots, X_k),$$

$$(i_X\omega)(X_1,\cdots, X_{k-1})=k\omega(X,X_1,\cdots,X_{k-1}),$$
for $X_i\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$; $1\leq i\leq k$.

It is easy to see that the operators $L_X$ and $A$ commute with each other; that is, for a covariant tensor field $K$, we have $$L_X(AK)=A(L_XK).$$

This commutativity condition fails in case of $i_X$ and $A$.

Let $K$ be a covariant tensor field of degree $r$. Let $X_2,\cdots,X_r$ be vector fields on $M$. We have

$$\begin{align}i_{X_1}(AK)(X_2,\cdots,X_r)=&r (AK)(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_r)\\
=&r\frac{1}{r!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_r}{\rm sgn}(\sigma) K(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(r)})\\ 
=&r\frac{1}{r!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_r|\sigma(1)=1}{\rm sgn}(\sigma) K(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(r)})+r\frac{1}{r!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_r|\sigma(1)\neq1}{\rm sgn}(\sigma) K(X_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(r)})\\ 
=&\frac{1}{(r-1)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{r-1}}{\rm sgn}(\sigma) K(X_1,X_{\sigma(2)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(r)})+({\rm something})\\
=&\frac{1}{(r-1)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{r-1}}{\rm sgn}(\sigma) i_{X_1}K(X_{\sigma(2)},\cdots,X_{\sigma(r)})+({\rm something})\\
=&A(i_{X_1}K)(X_2,\cdots,X_r)+({\rm something})
\end{align}$$

So, $i_X$ and $A$ does not really commute. We have
$$i_X(AK)(X_1,\cdots,X_r)=A(i_XK)(X_1,\cdots,X_r)+({\rm something})$$

I am trying to see if there is a nice expression for the ``something" part. It would just be an appropriate rearrangement of terms, but, I am not able to do it in a clever way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but isn't the interior product only defined for differential forms and not for general covariant tensor fields?

Comment: @AlexD Yes. interior product is defined only for differential forms... I took the liberty of extending the interior derivative to general covariant tensor fields :) Just put the vector field in first place :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a try:

$$ (i_{X_1}(AK))(X_2,\dots,X_r) $$
$$ = \frac{1}{(r-1)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_r}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)K(X_{\sigma(1)},\dots,X_{\sigma(r)})$$
$$ = \frac{1}{(r-1)!}\sum_{\alpha=1}^r\sum_{\sigma\in S_{r-1}}(-1)^{\alpha+1}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)K(X_\alpha,X_{\sigma(2)},\dots,X_{\sigma(r)})$$
$$ = \sum_{\alpha=1}^r(-1)^{\alpha+1}\frac{1}{(r-1)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{r-1}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)(i_{X_\alpha}K)(X_{\sigma(2)},\dots,X_{\sigma(r)})$$
$$ = \sum_{\alpha=1}^r(-1)^{\alpha+1}A(i_{X_\alpha}K)(X_1,\dots,\hat{X}_\alpha,\dots,X_r)$$

Here $\hat{X}_\alpha$ means that $X_\alpha$ is omitted.

Comment: This look very nice except that I could not figure out how you got $(-1) ^{\alpha+1}$ is coming.. Please explain...

Comment: I think you have to pick up that factor from the permutation. For each $\alpha$ you fix $\sigma(1)=\alpha$, so I think for a $\sigma\in S_r$ with $\sigma(1)=\alpha$, you have $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) = (-1)^{\alpha}\mathrm{\tau}$ for some $\tau\in S_{r-1}$. Think of it as dividing the permutation $\sigma$ into two parts: One part moves $\alpha$ to position $1$. This part contributes $(-1)^{\alpha+1}$ to the sign of $\sigma$. The other part is a permutation $\tau$ of the remaining indices.

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand it correctly.. we are writing $S_r$ as disjoint union of sets; each of which is of the form $\{\sigma\in S_r:\sigma(1)=i\}$ for $1\leq i\leq r$.. I see $\{\sigma\in S_r:\sigma(1)=1\}$ can be identified with $S_{r-1}$.. not sure what to do with the other subsets…